# Matlab to volttron integration

Tags: matlab, volttron

Below the steps followed to integrate a fake building - fake modbus device (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS) with matlab-based interface.

Following the documentation steps at: https://volttron.readthedocs.io/en/6.0/devguides/walkthroughs/DrivenMatlabAgent-Walkthrough.html

Installation steps for system running Matlab:
Install python (my Python version: 2.7.12)
Steps for system running Matlab:
Install python – done
Install pyzmq –done

Install Matlab-- done (R2019b)
run pyversion --done

version: '2.7'
   executable: '/home/USER_NAME/volttron/env/bin/python'
   library: 'libpython2.7.so.1.0'
   home: '/home/USER_NAME/volttron/env'
   isloaded: 0

when I run py.zmq.pyzmq_version() I get

ans =

Python str with no properties.

15.4.0

I copied the example.m to the desktop.

Run and test Matlab VOLTTRON Integration:
To run and test the integration: Assumptions

Device driver agent is already developed (master_driveragent-3.1.1- is installed)

Installation:
Install VOLTTRON –done
Add subtree volttron-applications under volttron/applications by using the following command –
For adding subtree: I used the code: git subtree add --prefix applications https://github.com/VOLTTRON/volttron-   applications.git develop --squash error (Working tree has modifications. Cannot add.)

Configuration
Copy example configuration file applications/pnnl/DrivenMatlabAgent/config_waterheater to volttron/config. done

error while installing Drivenmatlabagent in applications/pnnl/DrivenMatlabAgent

(volttron)whygrene@ip-172-31-8-77:~/volttron$ python scripts/install-agent.py -s ./applications/pnnl/DrivenMatlabAgent/setup.py --start
ERROR:install-agent.py:Invalid agent source directory specified.

and running example.m file in matlab server ?
Am i missing something

Comment: The link you reference is from version 4.1.  Perhaps it would be good to start with the master version (volttron 6), develop (volttron 6+) or if you feel like using python 3 the version that is located in the branch volttron-7-preview (soon to be develop branch)?  Note: volttron uses a bootstrap mechanism that installs the proper version of zmq for the platform (https://volttron.readthedocs.io/en/develop/setup/index.html)  Finally the new matlab agent:  https://volttron.readthedocs.io/en/develop/devguides/supporting/examples/MatLabAgent.html#matlab-agent

Comment: I was working on the volttron version 6 and following https://volttron.readthedocs.io/en/6.0/devguides/walkthroughs/DrivenMatlabAgent-Walkthrough.html link to ingtegrate to Volttron. Is above matlab link the updated one ?

Comment: auth: error: 'capabilities'
while executing  vctl auth add --credentials "public key "  in volttron device .